# Need to Convert List<T> to List<someClass> and Back

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic list assigned to a var `data`. The type of this list depends on previous code, and I need to return the generic type from the controller. It seems that I cannot have outside methods that [take a generic List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937301/how-to-return-a-generic-list-collection-in-c).

```
List<T> data = await queriedItems
        .Project(x => Mapper.Map<BsonDocument, T>(x)).ToListAsync();

if (data.GetType() == typeof(List<SomeClass>))
{
    data = someHelper.HelperMethodChangeData(data);
}
```

How do I handle this? I was thinking of creating a new `List<SomeClass>` var and then somehow converting it over `data` to that class, passing the specific type List type to my method, and then converting that back to a generic, if that's even possible. I don't think this matters, but the helper just takes a subset of the items in the List.

Edit - adding helper signature attempt to take generic:

```
public List<T> HelperMethodSignature<T>(List<T> itemsList)
```

Edit - and the original helper signature below:

```
public List<someClass> HelperMethodSignature(List<someClass> itemsList)
```

I excluded a bunch of irrelevant params.

Comment: If you are using autommaper and entity framework you should be using its [`QueryableExtensions`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) and using its `ProjectTo(` method, not `Mapper.Map`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Upvoted for good suggestion, but that's a mongoDb call. I use the QueryableExtension elsewhere (when hitting SQL via EF) and it's a great help.

Comment: I don't understand the case. You have a helper method that receives and returns`List<SomeClass>`?

Comment: @IvanStoev: Assume I am missing some fundamental C# concept, because that's probably what's happening. The problem is that I cannot (as far as I know) ensure that 'data' is of a concrete type, but I need to pass Data to a helper and work with it and then either return List<T> or return List<SomeClass> and convert it to List<T>.

Comment: @IvanStoev: If I can pass List<T> to a method that takes List<T> and returns List<T>, I am happy as well.

Comment: Please post the sample `HelperMethodChangeData` method signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you seeking for a simple cast.

Assuming the helper method is

```
public List<SomeClass> HelperMethodChangeData(List<SomeClass> data)
```

then you can call it like this

```
if (data is List<SomeClass>)
{
    data = (List<T>)someHelper.HelperMethodChangeData((List<SomeClass>)data);
}
```

Comment: The problem there is that I initially needs to do something like this 'List<someClass> dataInMyFormat = (List<someClass>)data;', which doesn't work. I can't just pass LIst<T> to something taking List<someClass>. Again, I could be missing something extremely obvious.

Comment: It's not considered a good practice in generic methods, but casting should work. See, you have a `List<T>`, but in fact your `T` is `SomeClass` (you know that because you are doing a check with `is` operator), so the actual list is of type `List<SomeClass>`, i.e. you can safely cast `List<T>` to `List<SomeClass>` and vice versa. The casts are needed to make compiler happy.

Comment: I had a stupid typo that was causing a problem and I couldn't get your solution working for a bit(due to my mistake). Your answer does work, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you don't do that. Code within a generic method *should not care what type T actually is.* The caller knows what type T actually is, so push that responsibility back onto the caller to handle any further type-specific changes.

The cleanest way would be to just return your `List<T>` from the method and let the caller perform any other operations it needs to after calling it.

Assuming that's not possible, you may just want to have the caller hand in a delegate that will deal with modifications.

```
public void ChangeList<T>(Action<List<T>> modifyList)
{
    var data = // get your data
    modifyList(data);

    // Do some more stuff
}
```

And the caller still retains that responsibility.

```
ChangeList<SomeClass>(data => /* do something with your List<SomeClass> */)
```