# Generic function return List C#

Tags: c#

I am new in c# and I reading now about generics functions. But I can*t understand what is wrong?  I have, for example, this function:

```
public List<T> CutText (List<T> list)
{
      foreach (var a in list)
      {
                a.Text = "Yes";
      }

      return list;
}
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?  What do you think `T` is?

Comment: Read this link for reference: [How to return a generic list collection in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937301/how-to-return-a-generic-list-collection-in-c). Basically you cannot use generic function parameters and return types, you need to either declare a custom class and use that, or use string list. If you want, I can give some examples as an answer.,

Comment: name T could not be found

Comment: If your function is generic, how can you suppose all objects passed will have the property `Text`? what if it is a list of `int`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Your function is not generic. This is just an invalid non-compilable function which returns a List of an unknown type T. Either your function or your class should have `<T>` in its declaration as well in order to make it generic.

   For example, like this:

   ```
   public List<T> CutText<T>(List<T> list)
   {
       foreach (var a in list)
       {
         a.Text = "Yes";
       }

       return list;
   }
   ```
2. Even if you mark it as generic, now type T does not have `Text` property until `T` is specified more precisely by a class or interface having `Text` property:

   ```
   public List<T> CutText<T>(List<T> list) where T : TextBox
   ```

   or

   ```
   public List<T> CutText<T>(List<T> list) where T : IAnyInterfaceHavingTextProperty
   ```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the downvote? This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Text property on?  You need to define a constraint so the generic knows what to expect.  For instance, `ITextControl` interface is an interface in the webforms framework, and if you defined it like the following, your code would work.

```
public List<T> CutText<T>(List<T> list)
   where T: ITextControl
```

But you have to define a where that the generic can understand.  Otherwise, it can't be strongly typed code like you have above.